# Mounting local external hard drive on a remote machine

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, remote

I have an external hard drive, which stores extremely large files. This is LOCAL and is connected to my laptop/desktop.

I run many different programs on a REMOTE Linux server.

I need to use some of the large files (stored in the external drive) as input to the program(s) that will run on the Linux server.

One solution is to FTP the large files from the external hard drive to the Linux server and then run the program(s).

This often leads to the following two problems:

- The server has space problems
- File transfer is time consuming

I want to know if there are some alternative solutions by which the data stored on the LOCAL external drive may become visible to my programs running on the REMOTE Linux server.

Comment: Why explicitly mention that it is a *external* volume? Why not `Mounting local filesystem on a remote machine` ?

Comment: Please don't post on multiple sites.  If good answers appear on both, it makes it challenging for future users

Answer (score 3):

Yes - NFS or SMB (also known as CIFS, or Samba.) If the remote server is over a high-latency link like a WAN, or internet VPN, your resulting performance may not meet your needs however.